# Select rows unique with conditions SQL

Tags: sql, select, unique

I have table like under picture.
Input is user name (example user01).
Output is all rows which user name = user input (example user01)
And at name column, it is unique.
What should i do SQL syntax ?
[image]

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [NAME], [USER] FROM TABLENAME WHERE [USER]='user01'
```

Comment: Thank for your help! But your syntax only get 2 columns: name and user. I want to get all column of rows output.

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT keyword to get unique Record.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [NAME], [USER] FROM TABLENAME WHERE [USER]='user01'

SELECT DISTINCT [NAME], [USER] FROM TABLENAME WHERE [USER]='user03'
```

Comment: Thank for your help! But your syntax only get 2 columns: name and user. I want to get all column of rows output.

Comment: Please check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

-- POSTGRESQL SYNTAX

-- USER ASKED WITH HIS NAME

```
SELECT user, 
       name 
  from "Your_TABLE"        
 where user in ('user01','user03');
```

Comment: Thank for your help! But your syntax only get 2 columns: name and user. I want to get all column of rows output.

Comment: if you want to take all columns : you write :
--postgresql syntax -->
SELECT * FROM 'Your_TABLE WHERE user in ('user01', 'user02')

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
; With Temp As (
Select  Row_Number() Over(Partition By Name, [User] Order By Name, [User]) As SRNO,
        RowId,
        Name,
        [User]
From TempData )
Select  RowId,
        Name,
        [User]
From Temp
Where [User] = 'User 01' And SRNO = 1
Order BY SRNO
```